# PreparedStatment batchExecute only excecuted the last batch

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

i am having trouble with the prepared statement batch excecuter:

```
try{
    while (operatorsQuery.next()) {
                phone = Integer.toString(operatorsQuery.getInt(1));
                prepStmt1 = connBlng.prepareStatement("update table set done='yes' where phone=?");

                prepStmt1.setString(1, phone);
                prepStmt1.addBatch();
    }
    prepStmt1.executeBatch();
} catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
        closeStatmentandRS(operatorsQuery, prepStmt1);
}
```

and for some reason it only updates the last batch(last phone).

why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prepStmt1 = connBlng.prepareStatement("update table set done='yes' where phone=?");
prepStmt1.setString(1, phone);
prepStmt1.addBatch();
```

you are invalidating the previous reference to `prepStmt1`, therefore the `batch` will only ever have the **last** element you tried to process.

What you want is this:

```
prepStmt1 = connBlng.prepareStatement("update table set done='yes' where phone=?");  
while(...)  
{  
     prepStmt1.setString(1, phone);
     prepStmt1.addBatch();
}
```

The fix is to only assign the parametrized SQL statement **once** and to flip the parameters on each pass.  Similar to how you would write a function and just change the inputs to it via a parameter list.

Comment: @susparsy thanks, please remember to accept if this is the answer so that others who have a similar problem can use the reference.